# Generate certificate for signing AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, air, certificate, code-signing

How do I generate a self-signed certificate to sign an adobe AIR app? I'm using the maven flexmojos plugin. I've followed an openssl tutorial to generate a .p12, but now the mvn plugin /adt compiler is telling me that the certificate is not a X509 certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Creating a self-signed certificate with ADT](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f74.html)